# Send custom CloudWatch metric time using Node AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

Is it possible to "tell" CloudWatch when a certain metric should be put on time graph?

Example:
My lambads process a 5 minutes interval every 5 minutes and processing usually takes 1-2 minutes.

So first successful process of day processes 00:00-00:05 interval and finishes at ~00:06. I would like to push metric then but I would like it to be stored under 00:00.

Same thing for second process. It processes 00:05-00:10 interval and finishes at ~00:11 but I would like it to be stored under 00:05.

Is it possible using Node's AWS SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

There is `Timestamp` field.